# -D- curl parameter

Tags: http, curl, parameters, request

There is a sample in [Jira API doc](https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-apis/jira-rest-apis/jira-rest-api-tutorials/jira-rest-api-example-basic-authentication):

```
curl -D- -X GET -H "Authorization: Basic ZnJlZDpmcmVk" -H "Content-Type: application/json" "http://kelpie9:8081/rest/api/2/issue/QA-31"
```

What exactly does the `-D-` parameter mean? There is no description in [curl documentation](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html).

I'm also not sure whether `-D-` and `-D` mean the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It dumps headers to stdout.

The -D flag dumps headers to a file, and the following - instructs it to dump to stdout. From the linked spec:

> -D, --dump-header
>
> Write the protocol headers to the specified file.

It doesn't specify for this option, but this works like other options that take a filename:

> Use "-" as filename to have the output sent to stdout.